# Dynamic JSON Array in flutter List View builder

Tags: flutter

I have a JSON response with the following structure.

```
[
  {
    "branch": "B1",
    "xyz": "0",
    "ABC": "2",
    "MN": "2"
  },
  {
    "branch": "B2",
    "xyz": "0",
    "ABC": "0",
    "MN": "0"
  },
]
```

In this, only branch is constant. The keys are dynamic in number(column names of a table). As per my requirement I keep altering the table by adding columns. I want to display these in my list view with a item for each branch.

I have used the following list view builder

```
 ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  var branch= snapshot.data[index]["branch"];// This is fine as branch is constant                     
  return Myownclass(branch:branch,);
   }),
```

How to get those dynamic keys( xyx,ABC,MN) and their values and display using custom widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [dartpad here](http://dartpad.dev/b702b024453b07b72a1d25bb194fb725) so you can play with the below code.

The code uses an index to enter into each part of the json object, which is then given to MyOwnClass, a stateful widget that extracts the keys from the json object (in makeWidgetChildren) and returns a lists of widgets using the extracted keys. and builds the listView using the keys.

I also  allowed for varying number of keys in each object to make it as generic as possible.

finally, I updated my answer to mimic getting the data from another source, such as an API call.  getJsonResponse() called in MyApp is meant to simulate this call, and how it would be passed to MakeList()

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: MakeList(json: getJsonResponse())),
    );
  }
  getJsonResponse(){  return [  
    {"branch": "B1", "xyz": "0", "ABC": "2", "MN": "2", "XYZ": "2"},
    {"branch": "B2", "xyz": "0", "ABC": "0", "MN": "0", "another": "sugar"},
    {"branch": "B3", "xyz": "1", "ABC": "1"},
    {"branch": "B4", "xyz": "0", "ABC": "5", "MN": "69"},
  ];}
}

class MakeList extends StatelessWidget {
final List<Map<String,String>> json;
  MakeList({this.json});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: json.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return MyOwnClass(jsonObject: json[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyOwnClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, String> jsonObject;

  MyOwnClass({this.jsonObject});

  @override
  _MyOwnClassState createState() => _MyOwnClassState();
}

class _MyOwnClassState extends State<MyOwnClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Container(
        child: Row(children: makeWidgetChildren(widget.jsonObject)),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> makeWidgetChildren(jsonObject) {
    List<Widget> children = [];
    jsonObject.keys.forEach(
      (key) => {
        children.add(
          Padding(
              child: Text('${jsonObject[key]}'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)),
        )
      },
    );
    return children;
  }
}
```

Comment: No. As the keys (ABC, xyz) etc are not known in advance, i can not use the statement like Text('${jsonObject['xyz']}'). Text('${jsonObject['ABC']}').

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  I updated my answer and the dartpad to give you dynamic keys

Comment: ... and also for a varying number of keys.

Comment: Thank u very much. Its working. One more help please. I am getting this response from an API call.  So I can not initialize the List. How do i add this JSON response to the List?.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you.   As for your JSON response, you shouldn't need to add it to the list, you should pass it to the widget itself.  I'll update my answer to put it outside of the widget

Comment: ok, I updated my answer.  I added getJsonResponse(), which would be where you would pass the json object to the widget itself.  If you're looking to add more and more objects to the same list, you probably need to start considering using state management to control the rebuilds. (i.e. Provider, BLoC, Scoped Model, etc.)

Comment: getJsonResponse() async {  
 
  final response = await http.get('http://10.0.2.2/getdata.php');
   var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(response.body);
  return [  
  
    
    jsonData,

 ] ;}  Am getting an error 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, String>>' as my API call is async?

Comment: so, be careful when you use var... you're hiding the actual type of the variable.  That error is because the type of variable returned by the API is not List<Map<String,String>>

Comment: in fact, It looks like json.decode must return a Future, because it says Future<dynamic>... and not a resolved future.

Comment: You'll need to add code that converts between the two cases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210048/discussion-between-william-terrill-and-raj).